# Assign each unique value of column to whole Dataframe as if data frame duplicate itself based on value of another column

Tags: python

i am trying to iterate value of column from df2 and assign each value of column from df2 to the df1.As if df1 will multiply itself based on value of column from df2.
let's say i have df1 as per below:

```
df1
1
2
3
```

and df2 as per below:

```
df2
A
B
C
```

I want third dataframe df3 will became like below:

```
df3
1 A
2 A
3 A
1 B
2 B
3 B
1 C
2 C
3 C
```

for now i have tried below code

```
for i, value in ACS_shock['scenario'].iteritems():

    df1['sec'] = df1[i] = value[:]
```

But when i generate the file from DF1 my output is like below:

```
1 A B C
2 A B C
3 A B C
```

Any idea how can i correct this code.
much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df1 = pd.Series([1,2,3])
>>> df1
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
>>> df2 = pd.Series(list('ABC'))
>>> df2
0    A
1    B
2    C
dtype: object

>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame({'df1': pd.concat([df1]*3).reset_index(drop=True),
                        'df2': np.repeat(df2, 3).reset_index(drop=True)})

>>> df3
   df1 df2
0    1   A
1    2   A
2    3   A
3    1   B
4    2   B
5    3   B
6    1   C
7    2   C
8    3   C
```

Comment: Thank you @Sayandip Dutta.Unfortunately i had error utilizing above code.First the error was reset_index and second: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 10 to array axis with dimension 33920

Comment: It seems like your dataframe has different shapes. If you could add a little more detail about the shape of the data, or a small sample of the data you are working with, it might be easier for me to answer. As you would see the answer works on the example that you povided.